# How to set static tab titles to SlidingTabsBasicFragment

Tags: java, android, static

In the current android developer sample SlidingTabsBasicFragment, the tabs are dynamically labelled as "Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3" by this code:

```
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return "Tab " + (position + 1);

    }
```

How do I set the tab titles to be unique words, instead of just a repeating title and number for each additional tab?

Thanks in advance!!

Regards,
Newbie Programmer

Comment: create an array or List and return String at position of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize this at the beginning of your adapter

`private String[] titles={"Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3"};`

Modify your getPageTitle:

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return titles[position];

}
```